# Create appointment for Office 365/Exchange Online programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, office365, exchange-server

I have task to create thousands of appointment for Office 365/Exchange Online programmatically with c#.
So far successfully testing Exchange Web Services .NET. 
Is there any other open source alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have a much more straightforward experience with the Microsoft Graph vs. EWS.  You'll need to register an application ID and get consent to be able to write to all calendars in the organization.

The next step would be authenticating properly to Office365.

Lastly, you will want to create calendar events:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You would do that on a per user basis.